# Allure Test report :

Tags: allure

Unable to generate Allure report with the following configurations in the project, kindly let us whether additional dependencies are required.

**Project Details**

- Cucumber framework
- Gradle Build
- Junit runner

**Build.gradle script**

```
buildscript 
{
    repositories 
    { 
        jcenter() 
    }

    dependencies 
    {
        classpath 'io.qameta.allure:allure-gradle:2.5'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'io.qameta.allure'

allure
{
    version = '2.6.0'
    autoconfigure = true
}
dependencies 
{
     compile group: 'ru.yandex.qatools.allure', name: 'allure-cucumber-jvm-adaptor', version: '1.2'
}
```

Comment: "Unable to generate" - so what happens instead? Is there any error message involved?

Comment: Allure-report folder is created and when I open index.html file in browser, it's opened in Allure report template but I could not see the content regarding test execution and not even the .xml files.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, try opening it in Firefox or failing that using the allure open command in allure cli.

```html
allure open <path to file>
```

Comment: I'm not able to generate even .xml files, let me know if I missed something (Adapter)